# How can I eager load objects that are referencing the primary key of my POCO class in a 1:Many relationship?

Tags: c#, .net, ormlite-servicestack

Considering the documentation here, you can define foreign key relationships in your pocos like the given example:

```
public class Customer
{
    [References(typeof(CustomerAddress))]
    public int PrimaryAddressId { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public CustomerAddress PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
}
```

This is fine, as there's a 1:1 relationship here. However, I have a 1:Many relationship I need to define, and the relationship is actually defined in the child object, not the parent object.

So, let's say I have these POCOs:

```
public class Customer
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public List<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerAddress
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int CustomerAddressId{ get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

How can I have ORMLite eager load the `CustomerAddresses` property in the `Customer` POCO?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `Db.LoadSelect<Customer>()` method and your customer(s) will retrieve CustomerAddresses (you need to add `[Reference]` attribute on top of your `CustomerAddresses` property).

Comment: LoadSelect seems to return a collection. If I write a repo method that takes an expression and returns just 1 object, and some other developer provides an expression that would return several (thousands) of objects, then the database is going to try to select all of those matches. Is there another method I can use that will eager load, but the database will return only 1 result? Essentially, I want `db.Single`, but with eager loading.

Comment: What about Db.LoadSingleById<Customer>(request.CustomerId) ?

Comment: I can't necessarily assume that I'll be querying by ID. However, I discovered `db.LoadReferences` which allows me to still use `db.Single` and pass an expression. The resulting SQL queries generated by ORMLite are essentially the same.